# How to persist and replay NestJS CQRS event and saga across restart?

Tags: cqrs, nestjs, event-sourcing

I am making an application which will need to use NestJS' CQRS module, as the requirements naturally lend themselves to that pattern.

Updates to the application logic are expected to be frequent and to happen during busy hours (that's just how my management works...), so the application needs to be able to restart gracefully. However, this means that events started just before the shutdown may not finish, or even if they do, some sagas may not trigger due to some events having happened before the restart... I'd like to ensure that doesn't happen.

I'm aware of NestJS' OnApplicationShutdown and OnApplicationBootstrap hooks, which is exactly for this purpose, but what I'm not sure is what I should do there. How can I capture all events that have unfinished handlers and sagas? Then after a restart, how can I make the event bus aware of the events monitored by sagas, without executing the already executed handlers?

I guess the second part could be worked around with a random ID per event/handler combo, that will be looked up in a log, and if present, the handler will be skipped, and if not, it will be executed and added to the log... But even with such a workaround, I don't see how I could do the first part. There will be a lot of events, and sagas (by definition) execute commands, meaning they have side effects... Even if all commands can become idempotent, the sheer quantity of events and frequent restarts means restarting from the very first command is a no go.

I've seen [this package](https://github.com/daypaio/nestjs-eventstore) but I'm not sure if it solves this particular use case, or if it's really just logging the events, and pretty much nothing more.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz Not in full, not really. I started an implementation for the event handlers, and sort of got stuck at the saga part. See https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/pull/172 .